# Connect MySQL trigger to a specific MySQL user

Tags: mysql, triggers

this question is answered differently in different sources, so I have to check with stackoverflow.

I have two users in my MySQL database: `database_admin` and `database_user`
I wrote a trigger:

```
delimiter //
    create trigger super_trigger...
delimiter;
```

How can I make it to work only for `database_admin`, but not for `database_user`

Comment: * One of the sources told that trigger will work only for the user that created it while another pointed to some fancy way where username was a part of the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the logic into the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER super_trigger ...
    FOR EACH ROW
       IF USER() LIKE 'database_admin@%' THEN
           ...
       END IF;
```

The USER() function returns the user that has executed the statement that invoked the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

That must be something like granting  permission to a particular user on that trigger, you might use this syntax to do that.. I am assigning all the permissions to user abc (accessed from any location %) on the trigger of a database.

```
 grant all on databaseName.TriggerName to abc@'%';

 flush privileges;
```